# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement when using loop to insert rows

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into an Oracle 11g table by running the following in Aqua Data Studio (version 15.0.11), using this:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..700 LOOP
        INSERT INTO lims.stock_template (
            stock_template_id,
            name,
            group_id,
            version,
            version_status,
            workflow_id,
            amount,
            stock_type_id,
            aliquot_template_id,
            auto_authorise,
            reorder_amount
            )
        VALUES (
            lims.sq_stock_template.nextval,
            lims.sq_stock_template.currval,
            21,
            1,
            'A',
            51881,
            0,
            103,
            2362,
            'F',
            0
            );
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

but I get the following error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 30-30 ------------------------
 ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
 Script line 30, statement line 1, column 0
```

If I run just the INSERT statement by itself, it works just fine, but I want to be able to insert multiple rows in one operation.

I'm sure that I've run something similar in the past, but I can't see what the problem is.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you included a BEGIN and END clause, which turns this into a "Anonymous PL/SQL Block"

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch15_03.htm

Within a PL/SQL block you can't execute a SQL statement directly.  You have to use only PL/SQL.  See attached example.[image]

Now you can create a stored procedure to execute your insert and use Script Object to Window As -> Execute or Execute Bind. See below screenshot.[image]

Comment: No true...  I do it all the time!

Answer (score 0):

In a stored procedure or a stored procedure within a package you can do whatever you like!

```
create or replace procedure testMe as

begin

    FOR i IN 1..700 LOOP
        INSERT INTO lims.stock_template (
            stock_template_id,
            name,
            group_id,
            version,
            version_status,
            workflow_id,
            amount,
            stock_type_id,
            aliquot_template_id,
            auto_authorise,
            reorder_amount
            )
        VALUES (
            lims.sq_stock_template.nextval,
            lims.sq_stock_template.currval,
            21,
            1,
            'A',
            51881,
            0,
            103,
            2362,
            'F',
            0
            );
    END LOOP;

end;
```

This is **EXACTLY** analogous to typing every line in at the SQL prompt form the word **begin** to the word **end;**.

What is more then likely tripping you up is the slash at the bottom.  In the CLI sqlPlus the end of the line with the semicolon ( `;` ) causes it to run the process, hence :

```
select 'A' from dual;
```

The semicolon tells it to execute.

IF on the other hand you type in the word **begin** then it shifts mode and will accept semicolons anywhere and just keep adding your strings to the buffer. ON A BLANK LINE the type the / and return and it will try and execute your code.

I think if you remove the slash it will execute quite nicely.